# Calling stored procedure entity framework dynamic result set using complex type

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I've a stored proc that calls a view with like 100 columns
the stored proc is called with a set of columns that the user want's to view and returns only those selected columns.

Entity framework cannot handle it because the complex type that I defined expects the 100 columns.

Let's say I call the stored proc with 'PersonName, PersonCity'
Is it possible that the other 98 types I defined in the complex type to be set as null?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Entity framework for this. You should use ADO.net and datatable for calling the SP and inspecting returned data structure. Something like this:

> var cmd = new SqlCommand("spName", db);
>               cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
>               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnNames", "a,b,c");
>               var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
>               DataTable dt = new DataTable();
>               da.Fill(dt);
>
> ```
>         foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
>         {
>             //now you have all the information about the results columns
>         }
> ```

Comment: Ok I know, but I have one parameter thats called ColumnNames. The result set is the changing part. Par1: ColumnNames = 'PersonName, PersonCity' or par1: ColumnNames = 'PersonName, PersonCity, GroupName'. What will cause a result set with 2 or 3 or even 50 columns. Entity Framework still expects the 100 columns.

Comment: Ok, so you can't use Entity framework for this. You should use ADO.net and datatable for calling the SP and inspecting returned data structure.

Comment: I was hoping not.. :) but I guess I have to do it anyway

Comment: If you think about it makes sense... Why do you want a well known structure for an unknown result?

Comment: Well that's true, but one thing is known the result set will always be one or more of the columns in the known structure

Comment: This is supported by the old "typed datasets". You define the row structure and use the dataAdapter.fill. If there is a missing column it will be null, but you keep strong typing.